# xml case insensitive replacements using external files and xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

i have as input the following xml file, input.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="ITEMS.DB">
   <DATA RECORDS="33673">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>asus</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="14">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>Creative labs</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="14">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>This is a test. Replace (all)</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

Then file search.txt:

```
ASUS
creative labs
This is a test. Replace (all)
```

and replace.txt:

```
GIGABYTE
LOGITECH
REPLACEMENT
```

I am looking for a way using xslt-2.0, to make case insensitive replacements, for each value found in search.txt, with the corresponding replacement value, found in file replace.txt, so the result xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="ITEMS.DB">
   <DATA RECORDS="33673">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>GIGABYTE</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>GIGABYTE</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>LOGITECH</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>LOGITECH</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>REPLACEMENT</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

The algorithm for replacements goes like this: whatever we find in row 1 of search.txt, must be replaced with what is found in row 1 of file replace.txt, and the xsl command, should accept as parameters the filenames, of search.txt, and replace.txt, found in the same directory with the xml, and xsl file. Only one MANUFACTURER element, may be found in each record. Apart from the . character, in the replacements, we may have also other special characters

Comment: Well, how should any algorithm determine that the single word "ASUS" has to be replaced by the word "GIGABYTE" while for the other replacement you want to replace two words "creative labs" by the single word "LOGITECH"? Somehow you need to structure your text files as XML or at least with some separator to allow to identify/separate terms.

Comment: this is where i have reached a dead end, i do not know how i could do a search and replace case insensitive replacement... thought it would be easy. The algorith goes like this: whatever we find in row 1 of search.txt, must be replaced with what is found in row 1 of file replace.txt

Comment: It is not a problem to use insensitive replace, but your question as posted has all data to be search for and to be replaced in a single line each, without any structure.

Comment: wrong formatted by my side of search.txt, and replace.txt, fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you have the search and replacement terms in each line of a text file and you expect there to be terms containing characters that need to be escaped in regular expressions I have now written the following stylesheet making use of the [functx](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/) library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="search-file" as="xs:string" select="'search.txt'"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement-file" as="xs:string" select="'replacement.txt'"/>


    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($search-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term))"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($replacement-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MANUFACTURER[$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="replace(., $matched-term, $replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $matched-term)], 'i')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That stylesheet works for me with your edited input snippets, I don't get any errors and the contents of the matched `MANUFACTURER` elements is replaced.

Comment: ao i cannot only give as parameters the filenames? Imagine the above is only sample data, so search and replace files contain hundreds of rows...

Comment: Well, sure, define the file name as a parameter `<xsl:param name="search-file" as="xs:string" select="'search.txt'"/>` and then the param I used as `<xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($search-file), '\r?\n')"/>`, do the same for the other file name and parameter.

Comment: and how i could also lock the search, in only element MANUFACTURER? now it searches all elements

Comment: or what if my search file has also some characters that need to be escaped? like a . character

Comment: As for doing the replacement on a certain element only, change `<xsl:template match="*[$search-terms[matches(., current(), 'i')]]">` to `<xsl:template match="MANUFACTURER[$search-terms[matches(., current(), 'i')]]">`.

Comment: As for escaping characters, see http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html.

Comment: I have added an example to show how to escape characters using the functx library function and how to match only the `MANUFACTURER` element.

Comment: thank you, only last minor request, i need to use search.txt, and replace.txt so could you update your last example?

Comment: Does the suggestion in the second comment not work for you?

Comment: i get many warnings like $search-terms[matches(.,
  current(), 'i')]]}: Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more
  items starting with a string, so i have missuenderstood something `<xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('search.txt'), '\r?\n')"/>
    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return lower-case($term)"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('replace.txt'), '\r?\n')"/>`

Comment: Can there be `MANUFACTURER` elements containing more than one term to be searched and replaced? Can you edit your question to show us a sample of such data and also explain whether you want to replace several terms in one element?

Comment: @kos_gu, I have edited the answer and included a single stylesheet only that reads from two text files and does the replacement fine for your input sample in the question. If you still get errors then please edit the question and show a minimal but complete input snippet that causes the error.

Comment: have made a new question, with real data, since i get errors only with the real data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538226/xml-search-and-replace-xsl-errors