# xml search and replace xsl errors

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="less.db">
   <DATA RECORDS="233673">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>asus</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="14">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>Creative</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="14">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>This is a test. Replace (all)</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

search.txt:

```
ASUS
creative
This is a test. Replace (all)
```

replace.txt

```
GIGABYTE
LOGITECH
REPLACEMENT
```

and the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="search-file" as="xs:string" select="'search.txt'"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement-file" as="xs:string" select="'replace.txt'"/>


    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($search-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term))"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($replacement-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:replace-multi" as="xs:string?"
        xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
        <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>
        <xsl:param name="changeFrom" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="changeTo" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="flags" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="
            if (count($changeFrom) > 0)
            then functx:replace-multi(
            replace($arg, $changeFrom[1],
            functx:if-absent($changeTo[1],''), $flags),
            $changeFrom[position() > 1],
            $changeTo[position() > 1])
            else $arg
            "/>

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MANUFACTURER[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(current(), $search-term, 'i')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="matched-terms" as="xs:string*" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="replacements" as="xs:string*" select="for $t in $matched-terms return $replace-terms[position() = index-of($search-terms-is, $t)]"/>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="functx:replace-multi(., $matched-terms, $replacements, 'i')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives as output, the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <TABLE NAME="less.db">
   <DATA RECORDS="233673">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>GIGABYTE</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>GIGABYTE</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="14">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>LOGITECH Labs</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>LOGITECH</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="14">
         <ID>1</ID>
         <ROW>0</ROW>
         <DATE>19/9/2003 12:31:54 μμ</DATE>
         <al>29/6/2005 10:46:42 πμ</al>
         <KIT>46123</KIT>
         <KAP>08</KAP>
         <YTE>A.IV.C.54</YTE>
         <HTE>0</HTE>
         <HEN>0</HEN>
         <SUM>0</SUM>
         <LYW>0</LYW>
         <AMF>29</AMF>
         <MANUFACTURER>REPLACEMENT</MANUFACTURER>
         <AME>pan</AME>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

How should the used xsl be made, so as to have an exact search and replace?
for example,  LOGITECH Labs is an undesired replacement. We wanted to replace only each element that has exactly the word creative (case insensitive replacement), and not this word, wherever it may be found in the MANUFACTURER element

Comment: Don't expect us to download and open zip files, try to identify the data that causes the problem and then show the relevant sample snippet in your question. I suspect that you have elements containing several search terms, you will need to explain what you want to do in that case, whether you will need to replace them all.

Comment: i was not able to identify the the data that causes the problem... the answer is yes, replace them all, if there are elements containing several search terms

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be caused by elements containing more than one search term, here is an adapted code sample that hopefully does not give that error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="search-file" as="xs:string" select="'search.txt'"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement-file" as="xs:string" select="'replace.txt'"/>


    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($search-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term))"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($replacement-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:replace-multi" as="xs:string?"
        xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
        <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>
        <xsl:param name="changeFrom" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="changeTo" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="flags" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="
            if (count($changeFrom) > 0)
            then functx:replace-multi(
            replace($arg, $changeFrom[1],
            functx:if-absent($changeTo[1],''), $flags),
            $changeFrom[position() > 1],
            $changeTo[position() > 1])
            else $arg
            "/>

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MANUFACTURER[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(current(), $search-term, 'i')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="matched-terms" as="xs:string*" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="replacements" as="xs:string*"
                select="for $t in $matched-terms return $replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $t)]"/>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="functx:replace-multi(., $matched-terms, $replacements, 'i')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: still got an error, inserted it into the edited question, in case it helps, without knowing what is wrong with record 18. Seems ok.

Comment: Edit the question to show us the data of `/TABLE/DATA[1]/RECORD[18]/MANUFACTURER[1]`

Comment: You might want to try whether changing `<xsl:variable name="replacements" as="xs:string*"select="for $t in $matched-terms return $replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $t)]"/>` to `<xsl:variable name="replacements" as="xs:string*"select="for $t in $matched-terms return $replace-terms[position() = index-of($search-terms-is, $t)]"/>` fixes the problem.

Comment: the above gives no errors anymore, but does not do an exact match. For example, Martin and Martin_Honnen, will both become author and author_Honnen, if for instance, we search for Martin, and the replace value is author. The desired result, would be to have as output only Martin be replaced

Comment: Well, I am not going to refine this answer further for you, perhaps someone else can do the work for you once you post the exact requirements you have.